# Close all mysql connections from workbench

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-workbench

I keep on getting the max_user_connections error on mysql
What I want to do is close every connection through something like workbench..

Anyone know how, on mysql workbench?

Thanks

Comment: Surely the answer here is to manage those connections correctly, so that you close connections when they are no longer needed.

Comment: Through the page by which you're connecting.